# eval() is not working inside UDF in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, dynamic, pyspark, eval, user-defined-functions

The following code failed when `eval` is called inside UDF. How to fix it?

```
### class
class myClass:
  def foo(self):
    return 'success'

### class method wrapper
def x(var):
  f=eval(var)()
  return f.foo()

### working fine
print x('myClass')

### if called with udf, will fail
udf1=udf(x)

l=['hello','hello1']
l= [{'a': i} for i in l] 
df = spark.createDataFrame(l)
df.withColumn('test',udf1(lit('myClass'))).show()
```

Output:
NameError: name 'myClass' is not defined

Comment: Is this running on a cluster? And how did you distribute your code?

Comment: Yes, on a cluster. I tested in spark shell.